# Why does my character stop moving after making some actions?

Tags: pokemon-go

At random moments, after making an action (eg, catching a Pokemon, opening a gym, etc.), my character on screen just stops walking, and I am forced to restart the game. It happens quite often, and it's 
really annoying.

I already searched for some solutions (turning GPS on high accuracy, etc.) but nothing has solved it yet.

I'm playing on a Samsung Galaxy Core 2. I know it's not the best phone to play it on, but I can't afford better right now.

Does anyone have the same problem or know a possible solution?

Comment: Probably your phone's memory can't keep up with the game.

Comment: If you have a lot of apps installed on your phone then try to uninstall the high memory usage apps. Or if possible do a factory reset of your phone then only install Pokemon Go and run it.

Comment: Where are you located? I ask this because if the game is not actually out in your country yet and you have installed the apk, this is one of the known issues for using the apk. I'm guessing it also sometimes doesn't let you move the screen around either or tap on the screen. Also might be due to the available RAM on your device although if you have no other apps open it should be fine. If I'm not mistaken it has a 700mb or something RAM and is a quad core processor, so should be sufficient enough to run the game if nothing else is running in the background.

Comment: Do the buttons in the bottom of the screen disappear (pokeball menu, nearby menu)? If not, does the application just freeze?

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like an app freeze, which is one of several possible effects of a software bug. The app stops responding because something's wrong in the code, for example, the program could be lost in an infinite loop, unable to break out and continue the usual operation. Sometimes, such a bug also causes the app to crash entirely. These effects both have similar root causes.

Since the cause for this problem is in the software code, there is no solution by the user. You can file a bug report and hope the issue is fixed in a future update, but this will take some time and until then, you will have to restart the app whenever this happens.

Answer (score 0):

Same happening on my HTC Desire 626s. I tried installing another rom (Sprint marshmallow)  and it did work better, but unfortunately it had other issues (not related to pokemon) and had to go back to my custom, it works badly again.